# Access file in android 12 after clear storage

Tags: android, android-12

we are developing the app with android 12(31 compiled version) without external storage permission. App created one file inside the public directory (Document). Once we cleared the storage from Phone->App setting and then reopen the app. The app try to read/access same file, but app can't access it. please note the file is their in the document folder.

Can anyone suggest what could be the solution.

Comment: Are you asking why your app cannot access a file when you DONT have external storage permission?

Comment: @MikkelT, In Android 12, App can create file inside public directory without write storage permission. So we just follow the same.

Comment: You did not explain what that clearing has to do with your problem.

Comment: `we created one file inside the public directory (Document)` Ok. But who is `we` ? Your app? Or how exactly did you do it?

Comment: @blackapps yes the app created the file.

Comment: My guess is, clearing storage has the same effect as uninstalling and reinstalling the app. And this [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/media#app-attribution#:~:text=If%20the%20user,newly%2Dinstalled%20one.) states that if the app is uninstalled and reinstalled, it would lose access to the media file in shared storage it created in last installation. Document in shared storage should behave the same as media file in shared storage.

Comment: You still did not tell what clearing has to do with your problem

Comment: @blackapps We are just trying to read last generated file inside the public folder. so we are clearing storage and again considering it as fresh installed app trying to read file.

Comment: I did a test clearing storage and cache and the file in Documents still is visible, readable and writable. Android 11 device. Aha... no Android 12 device..

Comment: Indeed. On an Android 12 emulator de file does not belong to the app anymore. But what i did not read here is that user has to confirm read/write permission again after clearing storage.

Comment: @blackapps I had given permission to read storage but still not work in Android 12.

Comment: You did not understand what i said i believe. And the file does not belong to the app anymore in Android 12 i confirmed. So this has changed.